# reshape data to different columns based on value from single column

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, tidyverse

Hi I have a dataframe as below (example)..

```
time <-c( 8/11/2017 10:21,  8/10/2017 22:34,    8/16/2017 2:28, 8/14/2017 6:17, 8/11/2017 6:33, 8/15/2017 23:46,    8/10/2017 20:10,    8/14/2017 3:35, 8/11/2017 4:09, 8/15/2017 21:05,    8/11/2017 2:16, 8/10/2017 18:17,    8/13/2017 10:02,    8/13/2017 9:08, 8/13/2017 8:32, 8/13/2017 8:20, 8/13/2017 7:56)

code  <- c( 1,  3,  2,  2,  1,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  1,  1,  2)    

var1 <-  c( 5,  11, 16, 22, 27, 33, 38, 44, 49, 55, 60, 66, 71, 77, 66, 71, 77)    

var2 <- c(  115,    66, 71, 33, 38, 110,    115,    121,    126,    132,    104,    66, 71, 77, 115,    121,    66)    

var3 <- c(  38, 44, 49, 55, 60, 66, 71, 77, 66, 71, 77, 132,    104,    66, 71, 77, 115)    

time    code    var1    var2    var3    
8/11/2017 10:21 1   5   115 38     
8/10/2017 22:34 3   11  66  44    
8/16/2017 2:28  2   16  71  49    
8/14/2017 6:17  2   22  33  55    
8/11/2017 6:33  1   27  38  60    
8/15/2017 23:46 2   33  110 66    
8/10/2017 20:10 2   38  115 71    
8/14/2017 3:35  1   44  121 77    
8/11/2017 4:09  1   49  126 66    
8/15/2017 21:05 2   55  132 71    
8/11/2017 2:16  2   60  104 77    
8/10/2017 18:17 2   66  66  132    
8/13/2017 10:02 2   71  71  104    
8/13/2017 9:08  2   77  77  66    
8/13/2017 8:32  1   66  115 71  
8/13/2017 8:20  1   71  121 77  
8/13/2017 7:56  2   77  66  115
```

I want to recast this dataframe using the column "code". The output I'm expecting should be as below.

```
time    code1_var1  code1_var2  code1_var3  code2_var1  code2_var2  code2_var3  code3_var1  code3_var2  code3_var3    
8/11/2017 10:21                                 
8/10/2017 22:34                                 
8/16/2017 2:28                                  
8/14/2017 6:17                                  
8/11/2017 6:33                                  
8/15/2017 23:46                                 
8/10/2017 20:10                                 
8/14/2017 3:35                                  
8/11/2017 4:09                                  
8/15/2017 21:05                                 
8/11/2017 2:16                                  
8/10/2017 18:17                                 
8/13/2017 10:02                                 
8/13/2017 9:08                                  
8/13/2017 8:32                                  
8/13/2017 8:20                                  
8/13/2017 7:56
```

But when I tried dcast funtion in R It is giving me an error for time variable.

Please help me with this reshaping objective

note: The result should have many NA because of reshaping and missing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be with `dcast` from "data.table" or even `reshape` from base R.

Assuming your vectors are collected in a `data.frame` named "d", try the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)
x <- dcast(d, time ~ code, value.var = paste0("var", 1:3))
head(x)
#               time var1_1 var1_2 var1_3 var2_1 var2_2 var2_3 var3_1 var3_2 var3_3
# 1: 8/10/2017 18:17     NA     66     NA     NA     66     NA     NA    132     NA
# 2: 8/10/2017 20:10     NA     38     NA     NA    115     NA     NA     71     NA
# 3: 8/10/2017 22:34     NA     NA     11     NA     NA     66     NA     NA     44
# 4: 8/11/2017 10:21      5     NA     NA    115     NA     NA     38     NA     NA
# 5:  8/11/2017 2:16     NA     60     NA     NA    104     NA     NA     77     NA
# 6:  8/11/2017 4:09     49     NA     NA    126     NA     NA     66     NA     NA
```

OR

```
reshape(d, direction = "wide", idvar = "time", timevar = "code")
```

---

If you wanted to use the `tidyverse`, you would need to first `gather`, then create a new "times" variable, and then reshape to the wide format:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  gather(variable, value, starts_with("var")) %>%
  unite(key, code, variable) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. But what I have posted is an example data. The real data I use doesnt have column names as (var1,var2..) The names are different for all column. Is there any way to modify your code so that it can be applied in my data.

Comment: @KathiravanMeeran, instead of using, for example, `value.var = paste0("var", 1:3)`, try something like `value.var = c("a", "vector", "of", "your", "actual", "column", "names")`, which you can easily subset from `names(yourdata)` if you have too many columns.

Comment: Thank you very much!!. It worked. May I know how you learn all this stuff? Can you suggest me some webpage or books?

Comment: @KathiravanMeeran, mostly exploring. Stackoverflow itself is a good place to learn.